# Playback a file to both sites of a call by DTMF request

Tags: asterisk

I want to play a sound file to both call legs whenever the caller clicks a DTMF,
I used asterisk features so if the caller clicks the dtmf 6 a sound file will be played to both call legs, The problem is asterisk features only allow the feature to run on one side of the call: self OR peer, 
I tried configuring 2 features with the same DTMF like that:
features.conf:

`[applicationmap]`

`PlaySound6p => 6,peer/peer,Playback,tt-monkeys`

`PlaySound6s => 6,self/peer,Playback,tt-monkeys`

but the playback of tt-monkeys works only 1 time, here is the log:

`--  Feature Found: PlaySound6p exten: PlaySound6p`

 `--  Playing 'tt-monkeys.slin' (language 'en')`

writting asterisk features show command returns:

`Dynamic Feature           Default Current`

`---------------           ------- -------`

`PlaySound6s               no def  6`

`PlaySound6p               no def  6`

It appears asterisk doesn't fire 2 features when they are configured on the same DTMF,
Anyone knows a way this can be done?
Thanks,
Rami.

Answer (score 0):

Only one feature can be fired by digit.

Digits will be "consumed" and not go after that.

However you can start on that digit one or more OTHER call, each one you can connect to this channel by ChanSpy or audiohooks and whatever you want.